# Is PHP Tidy still available in Centos 7

Tags: php, yum, centos7

I'm currently trying to install PHP Tidy on a CentOS 7 server (I'm running PHP Version 5.4.16 if that helps as well), but am having problems with the install.

I've been running (as per the documentation)

```
yum install php-tidy
```

but get the following error:

```
No package php-tidy available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've found someone having the same problem [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/307855-how-to-install-php-tidy-extension), and the answer is listed as

> When I installed via CentOS tidy.x86_64 and php-tidy.x86_64 were installed but Red Hat could not find the php-tidy.x86_64 rpm and I had to add the EPEL repository, then I managed to install php-tidy.x86_64 and it worked

...but I'm not sure what to make of that.

I've also found via the official [Tidy documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php):

> On Redhat-ish linux, you must install both libtidy and libtidy-devel (PHP 5.x):
>   sudo yum install libtidy libtidy-devel

...however I also get the same "No package..." error.

My only lead is that it doesn't appear that any of the documentation has to do with CentOS 7 (I believe they use CentOS 6 or 5, or an older version of PHP) and some of the suggestions are that some systems require `yum install php5-tidy` instead. So hence my original question on if Tidy is supported on CentOS 7, or if there is something else I might be doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the webtatic repo ... PHP 5.6 on CentOS/RHEL 7.1 and 6.7 via Yum

https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

php56w-tidy